# Encontrar string en archivo y volver arriba en archivo para extraer nombre de proceso

Tags: java, string, mongodb

Os explico: tengo una aplicación java que vuelca datos de todos los procesos ejecutándose en mi pc en un archivo de texto mediante un comando; este archivo se generara cada 5 segundos por ejemplo (thread). El archivo generado tiene unas 130000 lineas, por lo que no me va a ser muy efectivo en términos de velocidad de proceso eso de hacer loops dentro del archivo para encontrar un string.

Necesito encontrar una cadena de texto dentro de este archivo por ejemplo: `\Device\0000005x` y una vez encontrada, volver arriba unas cuantas lineas en el archivo para encontrar el nombre del proceso que lo esta ejecutando, algunos programadores me han sugerido el uso de bases de datos de documentos (NoSQL) pero estoy seguro de que tengan la función que necesito.

El formato en el que aparecen los procesos dentro del archivo es el siguiente:

(cada proceso esta delimitado por una linea de guiones "--",
 creo que esto puede ser de utilidad a la hora de pescar el nombre del proceso que esta justo en la siguiente linea) :

```
--

explorer.exe pid: 4632 WATCUT\tofpo

4: Process       
8: Mutant        
C: Unknown type 
10: Unknown type 
14: Directory     
18: Key           

--

SynTPEnh.exe pid: 3692 WATCUT\tofpo

4: Event         
8: WaitCompletionPacket

C: IoCompletion  
10: TpWorkerFactory 

14: IRTimer       
18: WaitCompletionPacket 

60: Key           HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Nls\Sorting\Versions

64: File          \Device\DeviceApi
68: IRTimer
```

Esto es solo un ejemplo, el archivo de texto es enorme como ya dije y consta de mas de 125000 lineas. Alguien que tenga hecho algo parecido o conocimientos de NoSQL databases que pueda arrojar algo de luz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si necesitas buscar una cadena de texto de vez en cuando no hay ningún problema en buscar línea a línea si contiene lo que quieres o no. yo uso también fichero de texto del tamaño que dices y se tarda menos en recorrer de la frecuencia de refresco del archivo que nos cuentas.

Yo haría una copia del archivo para que en medio de la búsqueda no de la casualidad de que se refresque y buscaría la cadena desde el principio hasta el final del archivo por si sale varias veces a lo largo de todo el archivo y guardaría esa copia por si necesito más información después.

Finalmente retrocedería hasta la línea anterior que contenga "pid" y cogería esa línea o hasta el primer espacio si sólo quieres el nombre del ejecutable. Si tu búsqueda aparece en varias líneas daría varios resultados concatenados.

Si eso no te funciona cuéntanos y buscamos otra solución, pero debería ser suficiente.

Yo no usaría una BD si no haces mucho uso de búsquedas ya que estar manteniendo la BD actualizada va a hacerte perder más redimiento que las búsquedas que tengas que hacer

**ACTUALIZO:**

Este es un ejemplo de código:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String descarga = args[0];
    String buscado = args[1];

    boolean encontrado = false;
    String strLineaPid = null;

    try {
        // Abrimos el archivo
        FileReader fstream = new FileReader(descarga);
        // Creamos el Buffer de Lectura
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(fstream);
        // Leer el archivo linea por linea
        String strLinea;

        while ((strLinea = buffer.readLine()) != null)   {
            //Guardo temporalmente la linea del proceso
            if(strLinea.contains("pid"))
                strLineaPid = strLinea;

            //Rompo el bucle y finalizo
            if(strLinea.contains(buscado)){
                encontrado = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        buffer.close();

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("Ocurrió un error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(encontrado)
        System.out.println("El proceso con " + buscado + " es " + strLineaPid);
    else
        System.out.println("Ningún processor con la palabra " + buscado);
}
```

Esta hecho para pasar por parametros la ruta y la palabra buscada. Lo ejecuté poniendo el "Prueba ruta-al-archivo palabraBuscada" La salida que me dío fue:

> El proceso con palabraBuscada es otroProceso.exe pid:2 lele

El archivo usado contenía lo siguiente:

---

proceso.exe pid:1 lala

otra linea

otra linea

--

otroProceso.exe pid:2 lele

linea buscada

--

otroProcesoMas.exe pid:3 lili

otra linea

---

Espero que con esto ya te valga.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Pero es que esa es la idea, la pregunta es como retrocedes hasta la linea contenedora del nombre de proceso y PID una vez encontrada esa String? He intentado recorrer el archivo, estoy disenando la applicacion con el Eclipse Luna, y por alguna razon el programa "rompe" despues de imprimir por pantalla las 4000 primeras lineas, a veces antes. La cadena solo se encontraria una vez, ya que solo un proceso puede estar haciendo uso de este "Device" a la vez, nunca se va a dar la situacion en que se utilice por mas de dos.  procesos en este caso.

Comment: Es fácil. Cuando recorras el archivo busca lo que quieres encontrar y el string "pid". Guarda la última línea con "pid". Si encuentras lo que quieres ese es tu proceso, si no lo encuentras se sobreescribe en el siguiente "pid" que encuentres

Comment: Si la teoria me la se... Un ejemplo practico es lo que busco

Comment: Te he actualizado la respuesta con el código que necesitas para todo.

Comment: Buena chaval Buenaaaaaaaaaa!! me acabas de alegrar el dia! lo acabo de probar y funciona! ;)

Comment: De nada. Ayudame votando la respuesta si puedes.

Comment: La he marcado como respuesta, pero no me deja votarla ;)

Comment: Creo que es por que tengo menos puntos de reputacion en stackoverflow espana